# Typing a username that is not in the database still gives me "username is already taken"

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

example of my firebase database: -Users -> -jjdsHGkjldsgJSKD -> -username: "kp", -email "kp@kp.com"

This is the code block to check is username exits in firebase database

```
mRef.child("Users").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot data: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            if (data.child("username").exists()) {
                Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "USERNAME IS ALREADY TAKEN", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.i("username", "Username used: " + data.child("username").getValue());
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

Comment: Are you not supposed to be comparing some real_username with the `value` of `data.child("username")` ?

Comment: I'm supposed to compare a value in the edittext field to a username in the database and I read that this database Snapchat can help with that but it's not working.

Comment: `edittext field` - and where is that in your code?

Comment: I know that part of the code is fine. Look into database snapshot.

Comment: Yeah, but Dude, you are not using using it in your comparison. Try reading and understanding the information I have given you, else you are just wasting my time.

Answer (score 0):

You're a bit off from what would work. This should be closer:

```
String valueFromInputText = "kishkish96";
mRef.child("Users")
    .orderByChild("username");
    .equalTo(valueFromInputText)
    .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
            Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "USERNAME IS ALREADY TAKEN", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.i("username", "Username used: " + data.child("username").getValue());
            count++;
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
       throw databaseError.toException(); // don't ignore exceptions
    }
});
```

The changes:

1. This code creates a query that only reads user nodes that have the same username as was entered.
2. It then checks if the snapshot exists. If it does, the user already exists.